# Manjaro: enable edit in Shutter

Tags: dependencies, manjaro, image-editor, aur, shutter

[image]

To enable edit button in Shutter sometimes a new dependency is needed.

In Ubuntu systems the neeeded package is `libgoo-canvas-perl`, but that is not present in Manjaro repositories, nor in AUR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for similar names and testing, I have found that the needed package is

`perl-goo-canvas`.

It is in AUR.

[image]